# Android SQLite DB version 2 error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I realize there are many answers here for SQLite versioning, but I couldn't find an answer for my specific issue.  I was doing fine with Version 1 for quite a while.  I then needed to add another column "TAG" to my table and implemented the following code in onUpgrade.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_TAG);
}
```

It worked great.  No issues.  The TAG column was working as expected reading and writing -- until I reinstalled after a full uninstall.  The DB now won't work using code that worked before the uninstall / reinstall.

I suspect it is because after uninstall / reinstall the "old version" is null (which is not < 2) and the TAG column is not being added.  I'm not entirely sure although.  Is my onUpgrade code the problem?

I suppose I could rewrite my my database as Version 1 with the TAG column, but I'd like to know what is wrong with my code for future reference.

**EDIT QUESTION**

OK, thanks for the responses so far.  I understand how to get the DB to work for someone who is installing the app fresh.  I also understand how to get the DB to work for someone who is going from Version 1 to Version 2.  I don't yet understand how to get it to work for both users (fresh install vs. someone who is just upgrading).

Comment: No oldversion cannot be null it is a primitive datatype. The error is somewhere else post the adb log.

Comment: Did you add the new TAG column to your DATABASE_CREATE statement?

Comment: I did not.  My "DATABASE_ALTER_TAG" adds the column.  I'm confused as to why I need to add it in onCreate and onUpgrade.

Comment: Because onupgrade is not called on fresh install. Its called for onUpgrade only, simple as that.

Comment: OK, what about for users that only need the upgrade vs. those that doenload the app at version 2??

Comment: For earlier users onupgrade will be called, so you dont have to worry, create database will not be called for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is definitely not correct. **Primitive data types are not object and hence are not null**.

Just make sure your **create statement** i.e. `db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);` reflects the new database table structure and not the old one i.e. with the new TAG column.

Comment: OK, I can do that.  I am confused as to why I need to add it there, when the onUpgrade statement also adds the column.  private static final String DATABASE_ALTER_TAG = "ALTER TABLE walk_run_table ADD COLUMN TAG TEXT;";

Comment: Because onupgrade is not called on fresh install. Its called for onUpgrade only, simple as that